# how to install readline and ncurses using conda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using conda in win 10, trying to install below 2 packages and it never succeed. The error is

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- conda-forge::ncurses

I did try different channels and it never work either.

Thanks.

```
conda install anaconda::readline
conda install conda-forge::ncurses
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - conda-forge::ncurses

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ncurses` is only available on these operating systems from conda-forge:

[image]

see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ncurses

Readline is only available for these operating systems:

[image]

(see https://anaconda.org/anaconda/readline)

These libraries cannot be installed using conda on windows. You can (probably) install them using MinGW, but that is probably not what you want to achieve. You might be better of using something like WSL